# defining arbitrary blocks

Tags: experiment-design, blocking

In an experiment with  4 treatments (a, b, c, d) and 3 
observation per treatment, is it valid or desirable
to impose $n$ blocks on the design.  That is
there is nothing that distinguishes the blocks.

So  run experiments 
block 1:  a, b, d,c
block 2:  c,d,a,b
block 3:  d,a,c,b

These labels assigned prior to experiment.

First four experimental runs assigned block 1,
second four runs assigned block 2, etc...

There is no reason to suspect a time or order effect.

There is nothing that distinguishes the blocks other 
than labeling.  Is this valid? Good?  Bad?

I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: As in put arbitrary "block" labels after you already obtained your data?

Comment: Labels attached prior to experiment, first 4 experm runs assigned block 1,

Comment: OK, but why would you do that? If there is nothing binding the first 4 experiments together then assigning a random label makes no difference.

Comment: In this case I did not set up the experiment;  but on reflection and following Hinkelmann and Kempthorne the analysis should follow the treatment randomization which was blocked.  Thanks.